# why isn't my simple function doing return false working?

Tags: javascript, function

```
<form id="form1" onsubmit="return hi(this);">
```

**#1**

```
function hi(bla){
    console.log("abc");
return false
}
```

**#2**

```
function hi(bla){
    console.log(abc);
return false
}
```

issue is, in #1 the function works perfectly while in #2 the page gets refreshed and i can't see where the issue is. i'd like to log a variable in the console in that function.

thank you for your time.

Comment: because `abc` is a variable and I am guessing you do not have a variable abc. So the browser is throwing the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: abc is not defined.` The error prevents the return false from executing and the form submits. In your console click the checkbox to preserve console on navigation. After you do that the error message will be there.

Comment: because of `(abc)`, abc seems to be undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mediaguru said the current code is missing.

```
var abc;
```

in #1

```
function hi(bla){
    console.log("abc");
return false
}
```

calling

```
hi();
```

will console log "abc"

I believe you want to change #2 to

```
function hi(bla){
console.log(bla);
return false
}
```

and then you want to call

```
hi("abc")
```

to display "abc" in your console.

**or more full example**

```
function hi(bla){
   console.log("abc");
}

var abc = "hi"
hi(abc)
// "hi"
```

You can go on to debug the value of this from there.

```
<form id="form1" onsubmit="return hi(this);">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the variable abc first. Put this before your existing code:

```
 var abc;
```